# Exercise 2, Chapter 5A, Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm looking for a solution verification.

**Question:** Suppose $S,T \in L(V)$ are such that $ST = TS$. Prove that null S is invariant under T.

**My solution:** Let $s \in \text{null }S$. Then $Ss=0$, and so $TSs=0$, and so $TSs=STs=0$.

$STs=0$ implies that $Ts \in \text{null }S$, hence we have $s \in \text{null }S \implies Ts \in \text{null }S$. Hence $\text{null }S$ is invariant under $T$

Comment: This site is not a proof checking machine.You have done a routine calculation and should be verified by yourself. Which step(s) you find difficult?

Comment: Seems correct to me.